# array_values kept associate key in my case

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array();
foreach($row as $data){
$array[$data] = array(
'id' => $data;
)
}
$result = array_values($array);

json_encode($result);
```

With above code, what I got is like this

```
[{"id":"123"},{"id":"456"},{"id":"987"}]
```

But why not `["123","456","987"]` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're effectively building an array whose elements are also arrays (each containing one element) with a `key` named `id` and a value `123`, `456` etc.

So if you'd like to receive an output like `["123","456","987"]` you should change your code to:

```
$array = array();
foreach($row as $data){
    $array[$data] = $data;
}
$result = array_values($array);

json_encode($result);
```

Btw I don't think you actually need `$data` to be a key in the created array so you could possibly end up with this code:

```
$array = array();
foreach($row as $data){
    $array[] = $data;
}
json_encode($array);
```

...but that depends on your needs.

Comment: that's to take only unqiue value, that's the purpose of that in my case.

Comment: His later code, which is what I had simultaously edited my answer to be, will give the output you desire: `["123","456","987"]`